# mo.js для нескольких объектов

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем.
Как можно применить анимацию mo.js к нескольким элементам, вернее ко всем элементам с одним и тем же классом?

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.my-button'),
 elSpan = el.querySelector('span'),
 // mo.js timeline obj
 timeline = new mojs.Timeline(),
 scaleCurve = mojs.easing.path('M0,100 L25,99.9999983 C26.2328835,75.0708847 19.7847843,0 100,0'),

 // tweens for the animation:

 // burst animation
 tween1 = new mojs.Burst({
  parent: el,
  duration: 1500,
  shape : 'circle',
  fill : [ '#e67e22', '#DE8AA0', '#8AAEDE', '#8ADEAD', '#DEC58A', '#8AD1DE' ],
  x: '50%',
  y: '50%',
  opacity: 0.8,
  childOptions: { radius: {20:0} },
  radius: {40:120},
  angle: {0: 180},
  count: 8,
  isSwirl: true,
  isRunLess: true,
  easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0.1, 1, 0.3, 1)
 }),
 // ring animation
 tween2 = new mojs.Transit({
  parent: el,
  duration: 750,
  type: 'circle',
  radius: {0: 50},
  fill: 'transparent',
  stroke: '#2ecc71',
  strokeWidth: {15:0},
  opacity: 0.6,
  x: '50%',     
  y: '50%',
  isRunLess: true,
  easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1)
 }),
 // icon scale animation
 tween3 = new mojs.Tween({
  duration : 900,
  onUpdate: function(progress) {
   if(progress > 0.3) {
    var scaleProgress = scaleCurve(progress);
    elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.transform = 'scale3d(' + scaleProgress + ',' + scaleProgress + ',1)';
    elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.color = '#2ecc71';
   } else {
    elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.transform = 'scale3d(0,0,1)';
    elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
   }
  }
 });

// add tweens to timeline:
timeline.add(tween1, tween2, tween3);

// when clicking the button start the timeline/animation:
el.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
 timeline.start();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    background: #ccc;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 height: 500px;
}

.my-button {
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 text-align:center;
}
svg {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.send-icon {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 40px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netgon.net/mo.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <button class="my-button">
  <span class="send-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></span>
 </button>
</div>
```

Пример на [codepen](http://goo.gl/Wi2Xh4)

Comment: простая замена querySelector на querySelectorAll не решает задачу

Comment: весь необходимый код должен быть непосредственно в вопросе, ссылка может служить дополнением

Comment: добавил код отдельно

Comment: к каким _нескольким_ элементам в примере идет попытка применить анимацию?

Comment: К тегу button с классом class="my-button", то есть к нескольким таким кнопкам с одним и тем же классом на одной странице.

Comment: чтобы при клике на каждую запускалась анимация именно для нее?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: Никто не подскажет?

Comment: не торопись :-) один день всего прошел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно просто вынести в функцию создание анимации для элемента, а потом просто применить ее для **всех** выбранных элементов. например так:

```js
function initAnimation(el) {
  var elSpan = el.querySelector('span'),
    // mo.js timeline obj
    timeline = new mojs.Timeline(),
    scaleCurve = mojs.easing.path('M0,100 L25,99.9999983 C26.2328835,75.0708847 19.7847843,0 100,0'),

    // tweens for the animation:

    // burst animation
    tween1 = new mojs.Burst({
      parent: el,
      duration: 1500,
      shape: 'circle',
      fill: ['#e67e22', '#DE8AA0', '#8AAEDE', '#8ADEAD', '#DEC58A', '#8AD1DE'],
      x: '50%',
      y: '50%',
      opacity: 0.8,
      childOptions: {
        radius: {
          20: 0
        }
      },
      radius: {
        40: 120
      },
      angle: {
        0: 180
      },
      count: 8,
      isSwirl: true,
      isRunLess: true,
      easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0.1, 1, 0.3, 1)
    }),
    // ring animation
    tween2 = new mojs.Transit({
      parent: el,
      duration: 750,
      type: 'circle',
      radius: {
        0: 50
      },
      fill: 'transparent',
      stroke: '#2ecc71',
      strokeWidth: {
        15: 0
      },
      opacity: 0.6,
      x: '50%',
      y: '50%',
      isRunLess: true,
      easing: mojs.easing.bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1)
    }),
    // icon scale animation
    tween3 = new mojs.Tween({
      duration: 900,
      onUpdate: function(progress) {
        if (progress > 0.3) {
          var scaleProgress = scaleCurve(progress);
          elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.transform = 'scale3d(' + scaleProgress + ',' + scaleProgress + ',1)';
          elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.color = '#2ecc71';
        } else {
          elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.transform = 'scale3d(0,0,1)';
          elSpan.style.WebkitTransform = elSpan.style.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
        }
      }
    });

  // add tweens to timeline:
  timeline.add(tween1, tween2, tween3);

  // when clicking the button start the timeline/animation:
  el.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    timeline.start();
  });
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.my-button'), initAnimation);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
}
.my-button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
svg {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.send-icon {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://netgon.net/mo.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="my-button">
    <span class="send-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="my-button">
    <span class="send-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="my-button">
    <span class="send-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="my-button">
    <span class="send-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```